# Efficiently find best-fit position of an image inside a larger image

Tags: python, image-processing

I have an image that is very close to being a cropped version of another image. (different averaged out images of the same location, mean taken to de-emphasize moving objects) and i want to figure out where to crop the larger image so that the images fit.

I have tried taking 2d correlation between the images to find the spot with the highest correlation and figure out the position using scipy.signal,correlate2d but it is highly inefficient.

Images were loaded using opencv and converted into numpy arrays.

Can anyone suggest an efficient way to do this in python?

Comment: Have you tried OpenCV template matching? See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/df/dfb/group__imgproc__object.html#ga586ebfb0a7fb604b35a23d85391329be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Template matching from Opencv library suits your [need](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_template_matching/py_template_matching.html)

Here in the link you can find the documentation and a very good example

Comment: That seems like exactly what i was looking for! didn't know it existed and it didn't end up in any of my searches. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I'm glad that it solved your problem. Could you please upvote and accept my answer?